# Language packs - translations

Tags: language

Is FreyaOS available in Slovak language? And also where can I find available language packs?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems like Slovak is available.

1. Go to System Settings >> Language & Region.
2. Click on the Unlock Button on the right upper corner and insert your password in the authentication window.
3. Click on the "+" symbol on the left lower corner and choose the language you want.

[image]